# Compiler throwing error for function return type returning structure pointer

Tags: c, struct

Can someone please explain why am I getting the compilation error the below code.

Error says:

> "expected unqualified-id before 'struct' " on line number 7 ".

My code:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

( struct node *) createNode(int num)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = num;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? They have different rules in this point, choose on language.

Comment: Define the function without starting paren like `struct node * createNode(int num) {`

Comment: why you are using brackets for the return type?

Comment: paranthesis are optional around expression. [primary-expression: (expression) ...] you can not use it around types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
( struct node *) createNode(int num)
```

to

```
struct node * createNode(int num)
```

Remember, you're specifying the *return type*. You're not `typecast`ing.

That said,

1. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. Always check for the return value of `malloc()` for success before using the returned pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Function: `( struct node *) createNode(int num)` is invalid syntax. A pointer to a `struct node*` is the return type of the function. It seems you may have thought you must cast it to the struct type. That is not necessary. Furthermore, there is no need to cast `malloc` in C. Change it to this.

```
struct node* createNode(int num)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

Not necessary, but, to save on typing `struct` each time, better yet, you can define a new type with `typedef`.

```
typedef struct node Node;

struct node{
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

While returning the structure you don't need to give the parenthesis for that. So simply You give the

```
  struct node * createNode(int num){
  ...
  }
```

Placing the brackets that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use parenthesis in return type of function definition. I think you are confused with the function definition here are few links:-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm

For function returning pointers

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_pointer_from_functions.htm

Type casting can only be use to a constant, variable, function calls (if returning something).

Explicit type conversion rule:-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm